# Getting rid of pointers and unmanaged code

Tags: c#

I've been trying to get rid of the unmanaged code that I'm currently using on my source code after a friend suggested why I shouldn't be using unmanaged code. However I seem to keep facing a couple of issues here and there. For most case scenarios I used Buffer.BlockCopy() as it seemed to be the most adequate method but there are still a few in which I'm not sure what to use.

Basically this is used to handle packets that are sent between a server and a client. WriteInt16 is a function used to write `ushort`values in the byte array for example. (1. is basically just doing this at offset 20 and 22).

I'll leave a couple examples below:

1.

```
fixed (byte* p = Data)
{
    *((ushort*)(p + 20)) = X;//x is an ushort
    *((ushort*)(p + 22)) = Y;//y is an ushort
}
```

2.

```
private byte* Ptr
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (byte* p = PData)
                return p;
        }
    }
```

3.

```
public unsafe void WriteInt16(ushort val)
    {
        try
        {
            *((ushort*)(Ptr + Count)) = val;
            Count += 2;
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a strong type for whatever this data represents? Side note: I like how it took your friend telling you it was unsafe rather than just realizing that from the keyword `unsafe` that you have to use.

Comment: I knew it was unsafe by the keyword, what I meant is that he explained me why I shouldn't be using unsafe code and its implications

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  It's hard to suggest alternatives when it's not clear what the purpose is.

Comment: Also an empty `catch{}` is bad practice whether or not the code is unsafe.

Comment: Basically this is used to handle packets that are sent between a server and a client. WriteInt16 is a function used to write `ushort`values in the byte array for example. (1. is basically just doing this at offset 20 and 22).

Comment: So use byte arrays instead of pointers?  It looks like this was ported from C++ using pointers instead of array indexers.  Note that `(ushort*)(p + 20)` is the same as `p[20]` in array syntax (or `p[10]` if the array is a `ushort[]`).

Comment: Also note that C# code is _never_ "unmanaged".  It can be "unsafe" but is is always still "managed" code.

Comment: I can't find a good example, but I think the usual way would be with [`BinaryWriter.Write(UInt16)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sh9zw1e) over the packet Stream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969993/how-send-data-tcp-in-binary-frame-format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming little Endian platform and byte arrays (not tested):

```
*((ushort*)(p + 20)) = X;
```

is

```
Data[20] = (byte)X;
Data[21] = (byte)(X >> 8);
```

and

```
*((ushort*)(Ptr + Count)) = val;
```

is

```
PData[Count] = (byte)val;
PData[Count + 1] = (byte)(val >> 8);
```